# Error pyomo encoding?

Tags: utf-8, pyomo

I am trying to solve a problem with pyomo (solver=ipopt). I have installed Anaconda in Windows10.

When I run it from spyder I get:

```
Solver log file: 'C:\Users\MC\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3ba3l1v5_ipopt.log'
Solver solution file: 'C:\Users\MC\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpf_uhkuem.pyomo.sol'
Solver problem files: ('C:\\Users\\MC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpf_uhkuem.pyomo.nl',)
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MC\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\MC\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\subprocess\processmngr.py", line 292, in _merged_reader
    encoding = sys.__stdout__.encoding
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

However, running the same problem from the command prompt I get the correct solution, the graphics, etc.

Any idea?

Comment: Have a look at the [this section of the `sys` module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__), specifically a the grey alert box. I don't know how to get things running, but this might help you better understand the problem.